# Javascript file input is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am not able to have below code working in IE. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Anyone can help, how can make this function work on IE?

```
 function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img_prev')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(160)
                .height(152);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does't work on any function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in the past. `FileReader` is not yet supported in IE:

http://html5demos.com/

You might need to rework your solution if IE support is required to include a regular file upload.

Comment: Not for dragging and dropping files, we ended up going with a flash file uploader http://www.easyalgo.com/eaflashupload.aspx It doesn't support drag and drop but was still a clean solution.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsDataURL()) has a [possible cross browser solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/6232/=crossbrowser_image_preview.html) for image previews.